# What is the physical explanation for the heat equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

We know that $\int{\vec v.\vec n \,\ d a}$=$\int{\nabla^2(u)\,\ dx \,\ dy \,\ dz}$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the heat flow and $u(x,y,z)$ is the temperature at the point $(x,y,z)$.and $ \vec v=- k \nabla( u) $ we can obtain the so-called equation about $\nabla^2(u)$ by using the divergence law ,but I'm wondering if there is a physical explanation for it.

Comment: These equations are themselves intuitive. Better deduce it from $J= \kappa(T_2 - T_1)\frac{A}{d}$ & then using it as a differential: $\Delta J=\kappa\,\Delta T\,\frac{\Delta A}{\Delta s}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point or another you will have to "understand" how a flux was converted into an integral over a volume, so the question is mostly about getting an intuitive approach to the divergence theorem, so my approach relies on that.

Suppose a volume and a $\vec{v}$ field as depicted: [image]

If we wanted to compute $\int{\vec v.\vec n \,\ d a}$ we could, according to the divergence theorem do: $\int{(\nabla.\vec {v}) d V}$. This makes sense if we look at the picture: the flux through the surface must be equal to the sum of all the divergences inside the volume. For example point x1 would have a positive divergence, x2 a negative divergence and x3 a divergence close to 0. That's what the divergence operator does on a vector field, it tells you the tendency of the vector field to flow out of the point you are considering.

So if we sum all those contributions from all of the points you must get the flux through the surface, since the small fluxes (divergences) have to go somewhere, if a point with positive divergence (source) is not cancelled by a point with negative divergence (sink) then they have to escape the volume.

Now with that in mind it's easy to see why $\int{\vec v.\vec n \,\ d a}$=$\int{\nabla\vec{v}\,\ dx \,\ dy \,\ dz}$ must hold. Going from there to your final desired form through intuition is what **tpg2114** has already done.

In conclusion it's a two step process, first you must understand why the divergence theorem is like that, and secondly why the Fourier's law holds.

Answer (score 0):

At the scale of the molecules, the "temperature" is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the molecules. Imagine you have a box full of molecules. These molecules all are moving around, bouncing off each other when they hit, and these collisions transfer momentum between the molecules when they hit. For now, let's assume the molecules are perfectly rigid spheres, like billiard balls.

When the temperature of the box is uniform, it means that the average kinetic energy of the molecules is uniform. So if we take a small region of our box and measure the average kinetic energy, it will match the average kinetic energy of any other small region of our box.

Okay, so now let's say that we split our box in half. On the left half, we add a lot of energy so that those molecules are, on average, moving much faster than the ones on the right. They have higher average kinetic energy, and so they are "hotter" -- higher temperature. We then remove the barrier that splits our box and the molecules can now move from the left to the right and from the right to the left.

When a molecule from the left side, where it is hotter, impacts a molecule on the right side, where it is colder, there is a transfer of momentum. The molecule from the left side leave the collision with a little less energy than it entered and the molecule from the right side leaves the collision with a little more energy. These collisions happen all the time and each time, the left side molecules transfer energy to the right side. This is increasing the temperature of the right molecules and decreasing the temperature of the left molecules.

The efficiency with which the left molecules can transfer their energy through collisions to the right molecules manifests itself as the heat conduction coefficient, $k$. And collisions take energy from the faster (hotter) molecules and gives it to the slower (colder) molecules. If all molecules have the same energy, there is no net transfer between them. This means that the energy transferred is along the direction of the gradient of energy, or $\nabla u$.

Comment: Thanks.but my main question was about the explanation for $\int{\vec v.\vec n \,\ d a}$=$\int{\nabla^2(u)\,\ dx \,\ dy \,\ dz}$ What does $  \nabla^2(u)\ $ shows?